# Java - Read all registered usernames from textfile

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I am learning the basics of FTP Client and Server programming in Java. I am now trying to implement a very simple login system by using a txt file to store the registered usernames from the Client into the server.

However, I have found the problem where it will only read the first registered line of the text file even though it has been shown to be registered in the console, i am still given the result of invalid username.

I have tried to fix the error by using read line buffered reader to supposedly read each line into the txt file, but I am still stuck. Are there any advice that I could follow? Thank you very much for helping me.

**Screenshots**

[image: Error shown from login attempt on newly created username][image: UserInfo]

**FTPClient.java**

```
class FTPClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
    Socket soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5217);
    transferfileClient t=new transferfileClient(soc);
    t.userLogin();

}
}

class transferfileClient
{
    Socket ClientSoc;

    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    BufferedReader br;
    transferfileClient(Socket soc)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientSoc=soc;
            din=new DataInputStream(ClientSoc.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(ClientSoc.getOutputStream());
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }       
    }

    void SendFile() throws Exception
    {       
        //Send File from Client to Server   
    }        

    public void userLogin() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Press 1 to LOGIN or 2 to CREATE a new account");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Choice :");
        int choice; 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if(choice==1)
        {

            validateUser();
        }

        else if(choice==2)
        {

            writeFileIO();
            userBack();
        }
    }

    void userBack() throws Exception {
        userLogin();
    }

    void validateUser() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader getIt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userName = "";

        try{ 
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("../FTPServer/userInfo.txt");

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            System.out.println("Enter your username");
            userName = getIt.readLine();

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                if (userName.equals(strLine)){
                    System.out.print("Successful Login\n");
                    displayMenu();
                }
                else{ 
                    System.out.println("Invalid Username");
                    userBack();
                }
            }

            in.close();
        }   catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
        System.out.println("\nError in validate user");
    }

}

    //Store new username into text file 
    public void writeFileIO()
    {
      while(true){ 
        System.out.print("Enter your new username: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = scan.nextLine();
        FileWriter fWriter = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try{
            fWriter = new FileWriter("../FTPServer/userInfo.txt", true);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
            writer.write(text);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Your new username has been created.");
            return;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}

//Successful login - show display menu for file transfer
public void displayMenu() throws Exception
    {   
        while(true)
        {   

            System.out.println("Files in directory");
            System.out.println("=========================");
            System.out.println("[ MENU ]");
            System.out.println("1. Upload File");
            System.out.println("2. Download File");
            System.out.println("3. Delete File");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            System.out.print("\nEnter Choice :");

            int menuchoice;
            menuchoice=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if(menuchoice==1)
            {
                dout.writeUTF("SEND");
                SendFile();
            }
            else if(menuchoice==2)
            {
                dout.writeUTF("GET");
                ReceiveFile();
            }
            else if(menuchoice==3)
            {
                dout.writeUTF("DEL");
            }
            else
            {
                dout.writeUTF("DISCONNECT");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in validateUser function:

Just put the else statement outside the while loop:

The reason:- The while loop runs, it checks the first line in the text file, it fails and then falls into the 'else' , the `userBack` function is then called, meaning the rest of the text file was not checked.

```
  void validateUser() throws Exception{
            BufferedReader getIt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String userName = "";

            try{ 
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("../FTPServer/userInfo.txt");

                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;

                System.out.println("Enter your username");
                userName = getIt.readLine();

                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                    if (userName.equals(strLine)){
                        System.out.print("Successful Login\n");
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                }

                 System.out.println("Invalid Username");
                        userBack();

                in.close();
            }   catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
            System.out.println("\nError in validate user");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! It worked :)